# How do you install Chrome Remote Desktop from .deb?

Tags: remote-desktop, remote, remote-access

I downloaded the .DEB from https://remotedesktop.google.com/access

I get this:

[image]

[image]

I'm on Kubuntu 22.04 LTS.

Comment: Details (on that Details tab) would help.

Comment: I doubt it. But added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As shown in the Status, you can't install the package due to having unmet dependencies, after a quick search I came across [this](https://packages.gentoo.org/packages/net-misc/chrome-remote-desktop/dependencies). However, those are for the version 110, while you are trying to install version 111. In order to solve the problem you need to install the missing dependencies, which you may find after running `sudo dpkg -i YOUR_DEB_PACKAGE`, after that, try installing those unmet dependencies that are listed using `sudo apt install XXX`.

Once you are finished, try installing the package again, either by using the GUI as you did at the beginning or running `sudo dpkg -i YOUR_DEB_PACKAGE`.

Comment: You can also use `apt` to install local debs, and apt will automatically satisfy those dependencies (if possible): `sudo apt install /path/to/package.deb`

Comment: Thank you! I'd been trying to install by double-clicking the .DEB file (on the desktop)...that seems to have launched QApt, which gave me that (unhelpful) message. I did `sudo dpkg -i chrome-remote-desktop_current_amd64.deb`, which produced a bunch of complaints about missing packages. Then I tried to install one of the missing packages with `sudo apt install python3-psutil` and got a suggestion to run  `sudo apt --fix-broken install`, which I did. Then I tried to install with `sudo apt install ...deb `, and it said it was already installed. It was! It works!

Comment: Am I correct to think that, in future, I should be installing .DEB files with `apt install <.DEB file>`, and not with `dpkg` or by double-clicking?

Comment: @nerdfever.com I have no idea if using one or other method is better (someone with more experience may be able to answer your question), but as far as I know, they are just different methods to install packages. You can use the one you feel more comfortable with (except for installing scripts, which is better to use the old fashioned apt-get instead of apt). Executing (double clicking) is the most friendly but won't tell what the problem is most of the time, when that happens, using the CLI will likely solve the issue as it is far more verbose. To sum up, I feel like there is no better method.